# Creating Attribute:Value Pairs in JSON Format

Tags: r, jsonlite, rjson, rjsonio

I am basically trying to replicate the following json structure with jsonlite (any other package like rson would also be fine if it works better).

```
 {
  "classes": [1, 2, 3],
  "ID": 0,
  "Name": "Peter",
  "Address": ""
}
```

My approach so far:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(list(classes=c(1, 2, 3), ID=0, Name="Peter", Address=""))
```

Which results in:

```
{"classes":[1,2,3],"ID":[0],"Name":["Peter"],"Address":[""]}
```

I think the problem is that everything in R is a vector, so even if I want just a single integer or string as an attribute it gets formatted as an array by enclosing it in [ ].

Comment: add the option `auto_unbox=TRUE` in `toJSON`

Comment: You are the best, Stéphane.